# configure: error: you must install the gnutls>=3.2.0 pkg-config module to compile libvirt

Tags: virtualization

I am trying to install libvirt-4.7.0 in a ubuntu machine version 14. I have downloaded the libvirt-4.7.0.tar.xz. Then extracted it to /usr/src directory. I have installed the libvirt dependencies using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get build libvirt
```

Then inside /usr/src/libvirt-4.7.0 directory i ran the following command to configure libvirt with esxi and xen driver

```
./configure --prefix=/usr --localstatedir=/var --sysconfdir=/etc --with-esx=yes --with-xen=yes
```

But I am getting the following error:
configure: error: you must install the gnutls>=3.2.0 pkg-config module to compile libvirt.

My ultimate target is to access hypervisor from remote pc. therefore i also need to get help in setting tcp connection over remote. For this what are the configurations needs to be done.???
Any help is appreciated....

Comment: Did you ran exactly `sudo apt-get build libvirt` or `sudo apt-get build-dep libvirt`? To solve your problem you need to run the latter one (see [`man apt-get`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/apt-get.8.html)). According to package information [Trusty has `gnutls.pc` in `libgnutls-dev` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=trusty&arch=amd64&searchon=contents&keywords=gnutls.pc), which has [version 2.12](https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libgnutls-dev). So it is very likely that you can not install such new version of libvirt on 14.04. At least Xenial has 3.4.10.

Comment: I agree to @N0rbert about build-dep, but in addition that will on Trusty install the build depends of the libvirt in Trusty and not the new one.
The new libvirt has much different needs, Trusty had 1.2.2 and comparing the build depends of 1.2.2 vs 4.7 in d/control shows me http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/J37qxyN8Qd/
For the current issue switching libgnutls-dev to libgnutls28-dev might be enough as Trusty has 3.2.11-2ubuntu1.1 - but better make sure you get all dependencies of the NEW package installed.

Comment: @N0rbert I also tried sudo apt-get built-dep libvirt. Still having the same error...

Comment: @ChristianEhrhardt I have also tried by installing libgnutls28-dev but still having same error ....

Comment: @M.P - did you also make the wrong old tls lib "unavailble" (removed it). A clean build environment is important and should always only exactly contain what is needed for a reliable build - I'd recommend using a lxd container or an sbuild environment.